# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery() is not updating a DATETIME column with a SQLite datetime() function

Tags: android, sqlite, date, sql-update

```
public Cursor set_datetime_next(Reminder r) {       
    String _newVal = "datetime('now', '+7 days')";
    String[] args = { new Integer(r.getID()).toString() };
    String query =
        "UPDATE " + DBConst.TABLE
      + " SET "   + DBConst.f_DATETIME_NEXT + "=" + _newVal
      + " WHERE " + DBConst.f_ID +"=?";
    Log.i(TAG, query);
    return db.rawQuery(query, args);
}
```

I have also tried passing in `datetime('now', '+7 days')` as a bound parameter, that will not work, as the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) says:

The values will be bound as Strings.

References:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html
- http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: is *_newval*: *datetime('now', '+7 days')* or *"datetime('now', '+7 days')"* ?

Comment: Hi Guido, I've updated the code sample to answer your question.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The cursor was not closed.

```
public void set_datetime_next(Reminder r, String _newVal) {     
    String[] args = { new Integer(r.getID()).toString() };
    String query =
        "UPDATE " + DBConst.TABLE
      + " SET "   + DBConst.f_DATETIME_NEXT + "=" + _newVal
      + " WHERE " + DBConst.f_ID +"=?";
    Log.i(TAG, query);
    Cursor cu = db.rawQuery(query, args);
    cu.moveToFirst();
    cu.close();     
}
```

While that makes sense, what really puzzles me is the requirement of calling `moveToFirst()` (or some other function which would "work with" the cursor in some way).
Without the call to both `moveToFirst()` and `close()`, the row was never updated.  `close()` by itself, after the `rawQuery()`, did nothing.

Comment: I've changed the return code to void since the caller had no reason to work with the result set, anyway.

Comment: thanks, this was a life saver! db handling on Android is really lousy implemented if you ask me

Comment: that is brilliant, the key point is moveToFirst() , I had problem after getting id from inserted record.The problem was solved by adding moveToFirst() before cursor begins. Look this;  cr.moveToFirst();
  int brandID = cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseTables.colBrandID));

Comment: Argh, that stupid moveToFirst has been killing me all day! Thanks for saving my bacon.

Comment: +1 This is very helpful. Although `moveToFirst()` makes no sense to me but gets the work done.

Comment: Hello @JD. I am getting cursor.getCount and cursor.getColumnCount as 0. Is there any way where we can get the count of updated rows ???

Answer (score 20):

Since it's an `UPDATE` statement you can use `execSQL()` rather than `rawQuery()`.  You wouldn't have to bother with cursors (which is kinda silly for an `UPDATE` statement).
However, you will have to place values in your `WHERE` statement instead of passing args, as `execSQL()` only accepts a single String argument for your SQL statement.  Also, `execSQL()` is of type void.

I use `execSQL()` for just about all SQL statements except `SELECT`...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, more intuitive than rawQuery for this case, by far.