# Updating SQLite fields not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an online page where I put SQLite queries and then on my Android app I iterate through them and execute them.. Here is the code:

```
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(Database.UpdateDB_URL);

            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            File dbfile = new File(Database.Database_PATH);

            SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                db.rawQuery(line.trim(), null);
            db.close();
            reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is an example of whats in line.trim() when the while loop is being run:

```
UPDATE Behavior SET Body="AAAAAA" WHERE _id=1
```

but when I browse the database in my phone I see that nothing's changed, but if I run this exact query on my pc, it works!
Why is that?

Comment: why do you send the query over the internet? why not use some sort of API mechanism and build the query on device?

Comment: I ship my app with a DB and I need to update some data in it from time to time..

Answer (score 0):

For Update Sqlite Use database.update() Query.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982663/android-database-sqlite-sqlitedatabase-rawquery-is-not-updating-a-datetime-col) thread, it worked out.. You just have to add the cursor object, moveToFirst, and then close it..