# Update query not updating the column using SQLite on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

In my app, when the activity is destroyed, I want to update a column value to 0. For that I have written the query, but it seems not to be working for me, because when ever I start the app I get the same old values.

#### Code

```
public void resetSelectOptions() {

    database = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    String query = "Update " + TableName + " SET " + Selected_Option + "=0";

    try {
        database.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {

    }
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use this method to updating the rows,**database.update()**  and
>   rawQuery is used to select query.

Answer (score 0):

`rawQuery()` only executes **queries** (SELECT).
For any other SQL **command**, use `execSQL()`.

So, simply convert this

```
database.rawQuery(query, null);
```

to this

```
database.execSQL(query, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not correct that the `rawQuery()` method executes only SELECT queries, it doesn't, but it is unnecessary to use it for an update, because you don't have any result - what to be iterated with the result Cursor at the ends, so try to use the `execSQL()` method. For more information take a look at this SO question [android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery() is not updating a DATETIME column with a SQLite datetime() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982663/android-database-sqlite-sqlitedatabase-rawquery-is-not-updating-a-datetime-col)

Comment: Please, learn about `rawQuery()`:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) and `execSQL()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)